# Cálculo de porcentagem no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma pequena dúvida que não estou conseguindo resolver, procurei aqui na comunidade, mas não encontrei exatamente o que quero.

Minha situação se assemelha com o seguinte: Tenho N registros de produtos no meu banco de dados. E nesses N registros, possuo apenas 3 códigos(não é a chave primária) diferentes para cada produto, que são: 4120, 5200 e 6150. Cada produto tem uma cor, independente do código. O que preciso é pegar a porcentagem de produtos existentes com cada código. E também, ver se a meta(um tipo de alerta) de cada código foi atingida. Exemplo(**não precisa ser no html, quero no sql server mesmo**):

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Código</td>
      <td>Porcentagem</td>
      <td>Meta</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>4120</td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>Atingida</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5200</td>
      <td>45%</td>
      <td>Atingida</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6120</td>
      <td>20%</td>
      <td>Não atingida</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Eu pensei em fazer esse problema da seguinte forma: pegar a quantidade de registros num select usando count.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID_PRODUTO) FROM PRODUTOS
```

Nessa parte comecei a ter dúvidas pois eu teria que pegar os código selecionados e fazer cálculos em cima desse total de registros encontrados. E depois verificar utilizando case when, se a porcentagem de cada código tivesse atingido 25%. Se sim, a meta foi atingida. Se não, a meta não foi atingida.

Não consegui resolver, queria entender como posso fazer isso, se possível usando apenas um select.

// Os campos necessários
Tabela: PRODUTOS
Campos: INT ID_PRODUTO, INT CODIGO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pode fazer assim:

```
DECLARE @quantidade as decimal(13, 2);
SELECT @quantidade = COUNT(ID_PRODUTO) FROM PRODUTOS

WITH CTE_PRODUTOS AS (
    SELECT 
        CODIGO,
        (COUNT(ID_PRODUTO) * 100) / @quantidade AS PORCENTAGEM
    FROM PRODUTOS
    GROUP BY CODIGO
)

SELECT 
    CODIGO, 
    PORCENTAGEM, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN PORCENTAGEM >= 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS META 
FROM CTE_PRODUTOS
```